# Cannot attach database created in VS2010 to SQL Server studio 2008 r2

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008-r2

I have created a database in VS2010 C# which I would like to attach to SQL Server 2008 R2 so that I can use the import wizard to import data from an Excel file for each table.

However, when I try to attach the `.mdf` file from docs/vs2010/projects/... etc I cannot select this in the SQL Server Management Studio window (see screenshot).

It will only let me select `.mdf` files from the SQL Server Management Studio 2008 program files location.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

img:

http://i1186.photobucket.com/albums/z373/barbsbargainsltd/q3_zps127dd713.jpg

Comment: Is this a **local** server on your own machine? If not: you **must** put the `.mdf` onto the server's harddisk - the server can **only** load from its own disks - it cannot reach down onto your local disk.... (and that's a *good thing!* )

Comment: My guess is if you move the file to c:\db or somehting similar, it might just work

Comment: Thanks for the response I think I understand. Yes this is a local server, I haven't done much, just installed server studio 2008 R2.

Another question if I may, in this case should I move the database files to the server location, then re-add this to the c# project in vs2010??

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't it possible the MDF you're looking at is already attached to another instance, or is open in Visual Studio? What happens if you try to rename it in Windows Explorer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to copy the    `.mdf` file from

> docs/vs2010/projects/... etc

to  the SQL Server Management Studio 2008 program files directory and then connect it again. If it does not allow to copy, detach database in options of VS, then copy.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have copied the file to the program files location, however receive the following error when trying to attach... "Failed to retrieve data for this request. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc)?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&LinkId=20476

Comment: ------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
------
CREATE FILE encountered operating system error 32(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15100) while attempting to open or create the physical file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\DebenhamsProjectOfficeDatabase.mdf'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 5123)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from the screenshot...In the dialog you can either browse, or you can manually type in the path to the file (including UNC paths to network assets), or you could copy the file into that location, which may be better anyway because then all your .mdf files are in one place.

Answer (score 0):

in normal case,You need to copy the mdf file to the data folder of your SQL Server(ie.C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA).as next step,you need to attach this database from your sql server window.Make sure that your database file extension is .mdf